# Implementing ListView with BaseAdapter fetching data from DB

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I'm trying to populate an android ListView with data from DB.

I've Created a class that extends BaseAdapter because I need to do a ListView with section headers.

So how can I implement the BaseAdapter extending class?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should extend a `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead, to help you handle the database activity.

Comment: Yeah but I want to make section headers like in this guide: [link](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) and it's implemented by BaseAdapter.

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter` is an extension of `BaseAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

Are your section headers from the DB as well, or are they arbitrary?

If they are from the DB, try using a `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`and `EpandableListView`.